# Version Number from Android Market Programatically

Tags: google-play, android-version

I am looking for a way to check the market version of my application compared to the installed version on the device and if diff, go to market to update.  I do not want to use a web service.  The code I pasted below does what I want by sending user to market on launch of application if the phone version is different from the market version (I don't understand how, but it does...if someone can explain this, great!)  I want to be able to give the user a choice if they visit the market.  Is there a result from the query that tells Android to go to market?  Is there a way to query the market for the version number?  Here is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse("market://search?q=" + APPLICATION_NAME));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Given code redirects user to Android Market to given app page and it does it **every time** the code is executed (no version comparing).

Comment: I would have thought the same, but I've run the code multiple times and the only time it redirects to the market is IF there is an update....that is why I am asking if anyone understands this behavior for it is not as expected.